# Abnormal modification of spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

The issue I encountered with JPA is that after using the findAll() method to query all data, I modified some data using the set method of the entity and then filtered out a specific record that I wanted to modify, and finally used the save method to save the modified record. However, it ended up executing SQL statements that updated all data that had previously been modified using set. How can I solve this problem?

I am very puzzled why the data will be modified in batches. It turns out that I have not encountered such a situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue that you met may be related to JPA's caching mechanism.
When we call findAll() method, JPA loads all entities into the persistence context. Any subsequent changes made to those entities within the persistence context are tracked automatically by JPA.
When we  modify an entity and then filter a record, indeed we are essentially modifying the entity that is already present in the persistence context. Then, when we call the save method, JPA detects that the modified entity is already present in the persistence context and triggers an update statement for that entity.
To solve this problem, you could try detaching the entities from the persistence context after modifying them using the set method. This can be done by calling the `EntityManager.detach(java.lang.Object entity)` method that tell JPA to stop tracking the entity, and any following modifications will not trigger any update statements.
I found some good examples [here](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-jpa-entitymanager-detach.html)